# How can I close a popup and redirect to another page in a Django View?

Tags: django, view, popup

I have a popup window which processes a form. After button click I need to close the popup window and return to the main page.
How can I do both actions in my Django view?

```
def InsertPopup (request):  
    if request.method == 'POST':  
        form = CustomerForm(request.POST)  
            if form.is_valid():  
               form.save(True)  
               return HttpResponse('<script type="text/javascript">window.close()</script>')
```

This code works fine but after the 'window.close' script I want to redirect/get focus back on the main page which shall show the updated data.
Many thanks for help.

Answer (score 7):

This isn't really specific to Django. You could set the location through JavaScript after closing the popup.

```
window.opener.parent.location.href = "/";
```

Comment: If you stay in the above example, directly after the window.close() should work: `return HttpResponse('<script type="text/javascript">window.close(); window.parent.location.href = '/';</script>')`.

Comment: I am getting a syntax error: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'. I am getting this error after submitting the form on the popup window. The error refers to the line with the script. Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: I messed up the quotes in my comment, the last parameter is supposed to use double quotes: `return HttpResponse('<script type="text/javascript">window.close(); window.parent.location.href = "/";</script>')`.

Comment: Now I am not getting any error, the form is submitted, data saved, the popup window closes ok but the home page does not reload. Do I miss anything on the submit button on the popup form, perhaps?

Comment: It's been a while since i last used popups, you might have to set `window.opener.parent.location.href` instead. I have updated my answer to reflect that. What's also a little hard to tell from your question is how you create the popup in this first place, this might have an influence on how it behaves.

Comment: Thank you very much Dirk. When correcting the line to 'window.opener.parent...' it worked.

Comment: @DirkEschler I want to redirect my parent window to an url which contains a variable of my view, but I can't use this variable in my HttpResponse. What I want is that my parent window redirects to "/<variable>/", and I am not able to set the href using this variable. Is there any solution?